Telebot Python 3.12 не имеет атрибута TeleBot
AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot' - ошибка на Python 3.12. На версии Python 3.8 работает всё ок, но на новой сопротивляется. Проверил множество решений, а именно:

Удалил telebot, поставил pyTelegramBotAPI
Создавал новые директории
Обновлял pyTelegramBotAPI

Итог никакой Взял код с документации.

Результат

Помогите пожалуйста

пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

А pip для установки телебота вызывали именно из того питона, который 3.12? Вы уверены? И трейс ошибки нужен полный и не в виде скриншота.

А рядом нет файла telebot.py случайно?

@insolor Отличное предположение, я уж и забыл про эту засаду, давно вопросов таких не было.

через командную строку и через директорию файла (терминал питон)

названия файла telebot.py нет
